# jquery form on the fly (adding multiple inputs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have minimal understanding of JS and JQuery
I'm trying to create a form on the fly using jquery (referring to http://www.joshuascottmccullough.com/index.php/2012/07/creating-submitting-a-form-on-the-fly/)
However i'm facing a problem when adding multiple inputs: This code below works:

```
   var form = $('<form>').attr('action', '/login').attr('method', 'post')
        .append($('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'username').attr('value', 'test')
        );
    $('body').append(form);
    form.submit();
```

However when I add 1 more input, it doesnt:

```
var form = $('<form>').attr('action', '/login').attr('method', 'post')
.append($('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'username').attr('value', 'test')
.append($('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'password').attr('value', 'password')
);
$('body').append(form);
form.submit();
```

What am i doing wrong here? How can I add multiple inputs to the form?

Thank you!

Comment: What is `);` on line `3` doing here?

Comment: Please stop with all those `attr`s! Just add an object as the second parameter, `$('<form>', {type: 'hidden', something: 'else', another: 'thing'}).appendTo('body');`. If you need to alter more than one attribute, use an object again `$('#someform').attr({type: 'hidden', something: 'else', another: 'thing'});`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. You did't close the `)` for append.

```
var form = $('<form>').attr('action', '/login').attr('method', 'post')
    .append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text').attr('name', 'username').attr('value', 'test'))
    .append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text').attr('name', 'username').attr('value', 'test'));
    $('body').append(form);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are now appending an input to an input. Either close the parenthesis after each append or create the form, then append inputs to it.

```
var form = $('<form>').attr('action', '/login').attr('method', 'post');
form.append($('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'username').attr('value', 'test'));
form.append($('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'password').attr('value', 'password'));
$('body').append(form);
form.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to append the second input to the first because your brackets are wrong. And they are hidden, so let's change them to text for now.

```
var form = $('<form>').attr('action', '/login').attr('method', 'post')
    .append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text').attr('name', 'username').attr('value', 'test'))
    .append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text').attr('name', 'password').attr('value', 'password'));
    $('body').append(form);
```

But the way you've done it is not particularly easy to read...

```
$('<form>', {
    'action': '/login',
    'method': 'post'
})
.append($('<input>', {
    'name': 'username',
    'type': 'hidden',
    'value': 'test'
}))
.append($('<input>', {
    'name': 'password',
    'type': 'hidden',
    'value': 'password'
}))
.appendTo('body');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gczunre5/